# Go command Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that is properly executing. Now, I tried to add `TRY CATCH` T-SQL statements.

After adding

```
BEGIN TRY

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO

/****** add new column Accountid  to Metainformation table ******/

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSCOLUMNS WHERE NAME = 'Accountid' AND ID = OBJECT_ID('[GSF].[dbo].[Metainformation]'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [GSF].[dbo].[Metainformation] ADD Accountid int 
END
GO



IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSCOLUMNS WHERE NAME = 'Accountid' AND ID = OBJECT_ID('[GSF].[dbo].[Metainformation]'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE [GSF].[dbo].[Metainformation]  
    SET MP.Accountid = AD.Accountid
    FROM [GSF].[dbo].[Metainformation] MI, [GSF].[dbo].[AccountDetails] AD
    WHERE MI.DetailID= AD.DetailID
END
GO
```

I get error in my `GO` statements, shows error saying incorrect syntax near GO.

Any pointers or alternative to use ?

**Updated Code:**

```
USE GSF
GO

/****** add new column AccountId  to MetaInformation table ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM **SYS.COLUMNS** WHERE NAME = 'AccountId' AND ID = OBJECT_ID('[GSF].[dbo].[MetaInformation]'))
    ALTER TABLE [GSF].[dbo].[MetaInformation] ADD AccountId uniqueidentifier 

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON


/****** If the column AccountId exists, Update all the AccountId values in MetaInformation from AccountDetails ******/

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM **SYS.COLUMNS** WHERE NAME = 'AccountId' AND ID = OBJECT_ID('[GSF].[dbo].[MetaInformation]'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE MP  
    SET MP.AccountId = AD.AccountId
    FROM [GSF].[dbo].[MetaInformation] MP
    **INNER JOIN**  
    [GSF].[dbo].[AccountDetails] AD
    ON MP.AllocationDetailId = AD.AllocationDetailId
END

/****** Drop AccountId column from AccountDetails ******/

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE NAME = 'AccountId' AND ID = OBJECT_ID('[GSF].[dbo].[AccountDetails]'))
    ALTER TABLE [GSF].[dbo].[AccountDetails] DROP COLUMN AccountId 


/****** add two new PStage values to [PStageToCategory] table ******/

INSERT INTO [GSF].[dbo].[PStageToCategory]
   (PStage, PStageToCategoryName)
   VALUES(19,1)

INSERT INTO [GSF].[dbo].[PStageToCategory]
   (PStage, PStageToCategoryName)
   VALUES(21,1)



/****** Drop and create new ViewName view to remove reference of AccountId ******/

USE GSF

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'ViewName')
DROP VIEW ViewName


DECLARE @sql_view NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql_view = '<VIEW DEFINITION>';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_view;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
SELECT
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
   ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
   ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
   ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
   ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
   ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

I'm using this script for Changing Schema in Production .So, am including try catch just to know the error and transaction to rollback if there is an error in the script(only one it will be run) in the run. Do you think it makes sense ?

Also, I have made changes to the my script according to your comments. What do you think ?

Comment: `GO` is **not** a valid T-SQL command - it's a delimiter used in the SQL Server Management Studio and it's valid there, only.

Comment: You'd need to show us some more code, preferably the whole lot, but at a guess you're trying to span multiple batches with a single `TRY` block - that doesn't work (batches are delimited by `GO`, and `GO` is a command to the client tools, not to SQL Server)

Comment: Thanks, Added code.Is there an alternative for GO ? or would not using it cause a problem ?

Comment: @Learner Just remove all `GO`s. You don't need them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor" -- Quote from [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx).

The sample code below assumes you are just executing a script from SSMS or one of the other utilities.

Here are some improvements to the code.

1 - The TRY/CATCH code blocks need to be in one batch.  Therefore, the GO needs to be after the block.

2 - The SYSCOLUMNS table is depreciated and will be removed from the product eventually.  See Jason [Strate's](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/07/lost-in-translation-deprecated-system-tables-introduction/) blog article on this topic.

3 - You do not need a BEGIN/END code block if there is one statement after the IF expression.

4 - You should avoid ANSI 92 joins since they do not work in SQL Server 2012.  See Mike Walsh's blog [article](http://www.straightpathsql.com/archives/2012/11/sql-server-join-syntax-its/) on this topic.

5 - There was a typo in which MP.Accountid was used instead of MI.Accountid.

6 - Use semicolons at the end of statements since there has be some buzz about this being a requirement in the future.

In summary, I use TRY/CATCH blocks when I write a stored procedure and want to return an error code back to the calling application.  This sample code just returns information about the error.

Sincerely

John

```
-- 
-- Use correct database and set session settings
--

-- Switch to correct database
USE [GSF];
GO

-- Change session settings
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
GO


--
-- My code block
--

BEGIN TRY

-- Add column if it does not exist
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.COLUMNS AS C WHERE C.NAME = 'Accountid' AND C.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Metainformation'))
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Metainformation] ADD Accountid INT;

-- Update the column regardless
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FROM SYS.COLUMNS AS C WHERE C.NAME = 'Accountid' AND C.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Metainformation'))
    UPDATE Metainformation
    SET Accountid = AD.Accountid
    FROM [dbo].[Metainformation] AS MI JOIN [dbo].[AccountDetails] AS AD ON MI.DetailID = AD.DetailID;

END TRY


--
-- My error handling
--

-- Error Handler
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
       ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
       ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
       ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
       ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH

GO
```

Comment: Updated the question for answering to your excellent analysis. What do you think ?

Comment: "4 - You should avoid ANSI 92 joins since they do not work in SQL Server 2012. See Mike Walsh's blog article on this topic." -- What doesn't work in SQL Server 2012 is the `*=` join operator, but that isn't part of the original code. Multiple unrelated tables "joined" in a `WHERE` clause is perfectly valid, and still works, as the article you linked to states near the end of "Review on SQL Join Syntax Evolution". Also, as that article states, the joins with the `JOIN` keyword are the "ANSI-92" joins, those aren't the ones to avoid.

Comment: @hvd Yes, mine is an explicit inner join and should be valid I guess ?

Comment: You are right that it only applies to outer joins.  (msdn article ) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx However, why still use an old school inner join syntax?  The ON key word makes it more apparent why is being joined.  By the way, the JOIN defaults to INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that you don't have any blank-space after your `GO_`.
Any space would alter the keyword `GO`. So just after each `GO`, do `ENTER`!

Answer (score 0):

Having seen your code, I'd recommend not to use the [`TRY...CATCH`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) at all:

> A TRY…CATCH construct cannot span multiple batches[<sup>1</sup>]. A TRY…CATCH construct cannot span multiple blocks of Transact-SQL statements. For example, a TRY…CATCH construct cannot span two BEGIN…END blocks of Transact-SQL statements and cannot span an IF…ELSE construct.

<sup>1</sup> Batches are sent as separate commands to SQL Server. The client tools need to know how to break a long script up into multiple batches to send to the server. By convention, most client tools (Management Studio, OSQL, etc) use [`GO`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement;

Comment: Right, What would be your advice to do the same ? I'm using this script for running Schema Change scripts for Database deployment. So I cant afford to lose data if one of the commands fail. That is the reason why I went for TRY..CATCH in the first place. Would you have any alternatives ? Thanks, appreciate the effort :)

Comment: You might want to wrap everything in a *transaction*. Transactions and Try/Catch are two separate things. If you're spanning multiple batches, you would still need to track separately whether everything is working correctly or not (if a batch contains an error, the client tool will report the error but will also continue to submit the next batch)